# Sourcing footnote data from the .bib file

Tags: footnotes

What I am trying  to do is  source the footnote data from the  .bib file, as in not  having to type the full reference for the footnote, just the  BibTex key as  you would  with citing  references.
How do I go about  doing this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can just place the `\cite` macro in the footnote. There are also packages that simplify this, but it depends on the overall set up of your file. Maybe you can provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we know what exactly is your problem and better help you.

Comment: @Aditya Are you maybe looking for the `\footfullcite` functionality from biblatex?

Comment: If and how footnote citations are possible will strongly depend on your bibliography and citation setup. Judging by your post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674809/35864 you currently have trouble getting it to run at all. So maybe focus on that first and then check out the documentation of the involved packages to see what they offer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully, maybe you want to create a key-value list for footnotes, to type something like `\footnotefull{first}` and get a footnote with the text "this is the first footnote"? In that case https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505474/moving-footnote-text-within-source-without-moving-labels/505497 may be relevant.