# Chicago referencing is not working no matter what

Tags: biblatex-chicago

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}


This is the introduction of your book. Write your content here.
\cite{chatterjee_museums_2016}

\printbibliography

\clearpage


\end{document}
```

What am I doing  wrong  with this  code, can someone point out.

The BibTex data of "ackerman_museums_2016" is as  follows and  it  has  no duplicates. The the .bib file of  the  document is  saved  where the  main .tex file is  saved. I have been at this  for  days but  cannot  figure where I am going wrong.

```
@book{chatterjee_museums_2016,
    edition = {1},
    title = {Museums, {Health} and {Well}-{Being}},
    isbn = {978-1-315-59654-9},
    url = {https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9781315596549},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    author = {Chatterjee, Helen},
    year = {2016},
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The code compiles for me

Comment: have you run biber  after pdflatex, then run pdflatex twice more

Comment: @JamesT - are you also able to cite the  literature?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I do it.

Comment: if your file is `file.tex` then type `pdflatex file` then `biber file` then  `pdflatex file` then  `pdflatex file` . If you get your editor to run commands for you, it probably has a menu item somewhere

Comment: As I wrote under your other question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674492/35864) you need to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (in this case "LaTeX" is most likely `pdflatex`) on your file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you need help with your editor, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: It would be much more useful to update your earlier questions and respond to comments than to just open a new question more or less ignoring earlier hints.

Answer (score 2):

(I've created this posting mainly so that the query can be considered to have received a "complete" answer.)

It would appear that you haven't run `biber` in between LaTeX runs. In the case the `biblatex` package is in use, a full compilation cycle is `pdflatex` - `biber` - `pdflatex`. (If you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX, make the appropriate substitution.)

I hope I don't sound needlessly harsh, but your code contains a number of serious weaknesses which you must address.

- In terms of *substance*, the bib entry you've shown is (a) missing an author (Guy Noble) and (b) lists an incorrect publication year (you write 2016, but it's actually 2013). You *really, really* need to correct such errors of substance. I hope you agree.
- I'd also get rid of *code clutter* caused by redundant items such as curly braces, `{` and `}`. E.g., I'd replace `title = {Museums, {Health} and {Well}-{Being}},` with `title = {Museums, Health and Well-Being},`. Removing code clutter is not only aesthetically satisfying, but it also makes debugging a lot easier.
- Finally, in terms of LaTeX *coding efficiency*, don't load obsolete packages (such as `times`), do load some very useful packages (such as `xurl`), and do remove unnecessary/pointless instructions (such as `\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont` and the final `\clearpage`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

%% Create 'library.bib' on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{library.bib}
@book{chatterjee_museums_2016,
    edition = {1},
    title = {Museums, Health and Well-Being},
    isbn = {978-1-315-59654-9},
    url = {https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9781315596549},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    author = {Chatterjee, Helen and Noble, Guy},
    year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

%%\usepackage{times} % <-- 'times' package is obsolete
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex} % 'biber' is the default backend nowadays
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow linebreaks in URLs everywhere
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

%%\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont % <-- unnecessary

\frontmatter %% <-- new
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter %% <-- new
\chapter{Introduction}

A citation call-out: \cite{chatterjee_museums_2016}.

\printbibliography

%%\clearpage % <-- unnecessary

\end{document}
```